# MFC-ActiveX is not refreshed/repainted automatically

Tags: events, mfc, activex, ocx

I have a MFC-based ActiveX control, where some important things do not work. A size-event is never called and the controls contents are redrawn only when I click the border of the control (in ActiveX test container).

That's my code for the size-event in header file:

```
public:
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
```

...and in source file:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CBeamConstruXCtrl, COleControl)
    ON_WM_SIZE()
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_OLEVERB(AFX_IDS_VERB_PROPERTIES, OnProperties)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void MyCtrl::OnPaint()
{
   //this is never called also when I change the size of the control in test container
}
```

Any ideas what is missing here?

Edit: just a clarification: OnSize() is called once in initialisation phase of the OCX, but never when I change the controls size.

Comment: You need to override `virtual void OnDraw(CDC* pdc, const CRect& rcBounds, const CRect& rcInvalid);` instead of handling WM_PAINT. Can't explain WM_SIZE without more info - is it a windowless control?

Comment: OK, it was OnDraw(), it solved both problems :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Roger Rowland: OnDraw() does the trick.